# Nativescript Cardview Style

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

It doesn't show me the border and shadow of the CardView, it shows just a long line.

[image]

I have also shared the code that I have been trying with Nativescript for Angular:

```
<StackLayout>
<ListView [items]="locs">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
     <CardView class="card-style" margin="10" radius="50">
       <GridLayout class="card-layout" rows="*,*,*,*,*,*" columns="*,*">
         <Image width="100" height="100" [src]="item.image" col="0" row="0" rowSpan="6"></Image>
         <Label [text]="item.name" fontWeight="Bold" col="1" row="0"></Label>
         <Label [text]="'Local: ' + item.local" fontWeight="Bold" col="1" row="1"></Label>
         <Label [text]="item.address" fontWeight="Bold" col="1" row="2"></Label>
         <Label [text]="item.phone" fontWeight="Bold" col="1" row="3"></Label>
         <Label [text]="item.city" col="1" row="4"></Label>
         <Label textWrap="true" [text]="item.schedule" col="1" row="5"></Label>
       </GridLayout>
     </CardView>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The next lines it should be added in the component.ts file:

```
import { registerElement } from '@nativescript/angular';
import { CardView } from '@nstudio/nativescript-cardview';
registerElement('CardView', () => CardView);
```